# Match pattern of urls in a pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am currently working on a drop which contains a big amount of links. 
So far I want to filter the links to a list of websites. 
So I wrote an array which contains the xxx-value of every website:
www.xxx.de/com/whatever
What I want to do is to check every column entry with the values which are in the array.

```
list = ['forbes','bloomberg',...]
map = df['URL'].match(list)
df['URL'] = df.apply(map)
```

Somehow in this manner. I am just not so sure how to work with the link which in the column since I never worked with strings before. 
Links are in the following format:

```
www.forbes.com/.../...
```

Is there any easy way without using urlparse or similar to do this job?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for new column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'URL':['www.forbes.com/.../...',
                          'www.bloomberg.com/something',
                          'www.webpage.com/something']})


L = ['forbes','bloomberg']
df['new'] = df['URL'].str.extract("(" + "|".join(L) +")", expand=False)
print (df)
                           URL        new
0       www.forbes.com/.../...     forbes
1  www.bloomberg.com/something  bloomberg
2    www.webpage.com/something        NaN
```

But if want filter rows only use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df = df[df['URL'].str.contains("|".join(L))]
print (df)
                           URL
0       www.forbes.com/.../...
1  www.bloomberg.com/something
```